# Is there any easy way to implement a rejected suggestion on a post of mine?

Tags: support, edits

So, someone suggested an edit on one of my answers.

When I opened the notification, the edit had already been rejected with reason:

> This edit was intended to address the author of the post and makes no sense as an edit. It should have been written as a comment or an answer.

But.. actually I agree with that edit, and think it would improve my answer. I understand that, since the suggestion was rejected, I can't have it approved anymore, and the suggester won't get rep for his effort.

Still, is there any easy way to implement that edit *myself* on my answer, *as mine*?

For simple edits, it takes a few seconds, but when much has changed, it might take a few minutes. Not much, but I wonder if there's any simpler way.

- I have thought about clicking `markdown` and copying the whole suggested answer, but identical lines are skipped, so it takes some work with two pages side by side.
- I guess this does not happen frequently? So a feature request for a `I like this edit! Implement it in my post` button would be rejected.

Any suggestion? Plus: how frequent is this - agreeing with a rejected suggestion on your own post?